# Why does thin dashed line appear solid if length is even?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

[image: LineWidth examples]

I've been playing with dashed lines on the HTML5 canvas, and I have run into a roadblock. If I set a LineDash of [2,2,2,2,2] the line looks nearly solid if it's an even number of pixels long. It looks more clearly dashed if it's an odd number of pixels long. I get the same results on my Mac in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Here is simple code showing the effect:

```
context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = '#990000';
context.setLineDash([2,2,2,2,2]);

// Line ends on an even y-coordinate
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(2,0);
context.lineTo(2,94);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();

// Line ends on an odd y-coordinate
context.strokeStyle = '#000099';

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(102,0);
context.lineTo(102,95);
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

Also, neither LineWidth (thickness) nor orientation fix the problem. The problem persists if I change LineWidth from 1 to any other value. And it persists whether the line is horizontal or vertical.

I put a bunch of examples in this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENLwdb

Why should the length matter at all? Shouldn't the dash pattern appear the same regardless of length?

Is my only recourse to alter line lengths if I detect they are even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the code is using `closePath()` on a line which makes it add an extra line on top, from the end point back to the starting point. Depending on the length and pattern the returning line may or may not fill the remaining gaps.

Remove the `closePath()` (which is only needed to close paths for stroked polygon shapes) and it will work.

**[Modified CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNRERX)**

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I never would have figured that out. So closePath() is not for lines, ellipses, arcs, etc? Only closed polygons?

Comment: how would one close-off a line? ;)

Comment: @Kirkman14 you can use it for ellipses, arcs, and complex shapes made from line segements etc., but not for a single line. And it's only really needed for strokes as fill() will internally close the shape.

Comment: @dandavis: I just misunderstood what it was for. I assumed that since you need to indicate you are drawing a new path with beginPath(), you would indicate when you were finished with closePath().

Comment: @Kirkman14: i didn't see it either, but afterwards it was a facepalm...